# How to use Laravel URL::asset in jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'd like to use URL::asset to pass url to javascript 
instead of direct url

```
$("select#lang").css("background-image", 'url(http://pascha.org/img/' + $("select#lang").val() + '.png)');
```

I'd like do something like this:

```
$("select#lang").css("background-image", '{{ URL::asset('/images/flags/') }}' + $("select#lang").val() + '.png)');
```

but this of course doesn't work and question is how it should be look if is is possoble at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why doesn't this work?

```
$("select#lang").css("background-image",
  '{{ URL::asset('/images/flags/') }}' + $("select#lang").val() + '.png)');
```

The only reason it wouldn't work is if you're doing this outside of your blade file and in a separate JS file. Unless I've missed something?

If you do have a separate JS file, you could assign some "global" variables in the blade file before your JS file is declared in your markup.

For example:

```
<script>
    // "global" vars, built using blade
    var flagsUrl = '{{ URL::asset('/images/flags/') }}';
</script>
<script src="your-js-file.js"></script>
```

Then in *your-js-file.js*, you can do this:

```
$("select#lang").css("background-image",
  flagsUrl + $("select#lang").val() + '.png)');
```

Comment: You have right, js must be in blade file not in separately js scripts. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because your javascript file (something.js) is not parsed by PHP. Meaning, PHP doesn't check javascript files for php code.

Although you can pass variables between them. The simplest way is to do something like this in your view (blade file):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '{{ URL::asset('/images/flags/') }}'
</script>
```

In your javascript, you now have a global variable called `url` with the value you are looking for and you can use it in you javascript file:

```
$("select#lang").css("background-image", url + $("select#lang").val() + '.png)');
```

Comment: var url must be in quotation marks `var flagsUrl = '{{ URL::asset('/images/flags/') }}';`

Comment: And semicolon at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 $("select#lang").css("background-image", 'url(/images/flags/'+ $("select#lang").val() + '.png)');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you paste image to folder public/images/abc.png
You can use

> '/images/'

instead of

> {{ URL::asset('/images') }}

in your js file.

Example in .blade :

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset('/images') }}/abc.png" />
```

in .js :

```
var image = "<img src='/images/abc.png' />";
```